# How to create columns for days of the week?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The database I am working with has a separate entry an employee's start time each day. I want to create columns for the start on each day of the week - "Monday Start Time", "Tuesday Start Time", etc. [Example of the table schema I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJqjQ.png)

I tried this but it returns multiple results in the subquery:

```
select "Employee Number", "Employee Name"
  , (select `Start Time` from start_times WHERE `Day` = "Monday") AS "Monday Start"
from start_times
```

[Example Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0kO7.png)

Comment: The data seems poorly structured. What do you want to do if one user has two different rows for Monday? What if the data covers more than a single week? Also why repeat "Bob Smith" in the table multiple times, surely only the number is needed (and the name can be derived from the Employees table)?

Comment: That query won't work in SQL Server, T-SQL doesn't use backticks (`\``) for delimit identifying. Are you *sure* you're using SQL Server?

Comment: If you really want a wide format (which would only work if the employee has one row per DOW), then you could create a CTE for each DOW and join to them on employee id.

Comment: A pivot would likely be more performant than 5 `JOIN`s to the same table, @Isolated .

Comment: @Larnu Absolutely, thanks. I haven't needed the use of pivot and often forget about that function.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is a `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable
PIVOT 
(
  MAX([Start Time]) FOR [Day] IN 
  ([Monday],[Tuesday],[Wednesday],[Thursday],[Friday])
) AS p;
```

The results aren't *exactly* as you wanted but you can apply whatever column labels you want after the fact.

Working example in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pz1QQhWM).